# Preg Replace in sub string leaving a part of the string remaining

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using `preg_replace`

I am trying to replace everything between (and ideally including): [BW] and [/BW] with an empty string.

```
$string = MyText-[BW]field[/BW]-[COUNTER]0001[/COUNTER]-[D]YY/MM/DD[/D][BW]field_2[/BW]
$string = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote('[BW]').'[\s\S]+?'.'[\/BW]'.'/', '', $string);
```

However the output I am getting seems to be keeping the follwing part: `BW]`

i.e. `MyText-BW]-[COUNTER]0001[/COUNTER]-[D]YY/MM/DD[/D]BW]`

The result I want is `MyText--[COUNTER]0001[/COUNTER]-[D]YY/MM/DD[/D]`

I have a workaround for this but i would prefer implement the function properly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `preg_quote` the latter portion of your search pattern.  Fix that, and it works:

```php
$string = MyText-[BW]field[/BW]-[COUNTER]0001[/COUNTER]-[D]YY/MM/DD[/D][BW]field_2[/BW]
$string = preg_replace('#'.preg_quote('[BW]').'[\s\S]+?'.preg_quote('[/BW]').'#', '', $string); 
echo $string;  // MyText--[COUNTER]0001[/COUNTER]-[D]YY/MM/DD[/D]
```

To avoid the issue with `preg_quote()` escaping backslash when used to escape the `/` delimiter, I have switched to using `#` as a delimiter.

Comment: Ah thank you! I had tried that but never thought to use #

Comment: As a side note, I would consider it more canonical for a known/fixed pattern to _not_ use `preg_quote()` but instead to just write out the escaped pattern.